CSS: deepest in DOM priority
I have a .card component with two variants:


.card {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  &.is-dark {
    background: #151515;
    p {
      color: white;
    }
  }
  &.is-light {
    background: #fcfcfd;
    p {
      color: #111;
    }
  }
}
<div class="card is-light">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-dark">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card is-dark">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-light">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>



But as visible in the snippet, for both <p>, the matching selectors are .card.is-dark p and .card.is-light p and the second wins as it is the last, while I'd expect text to be white in the .card.is-light .card.is-dark p case.

Is there any chance I could tell my CSS to match the deepest in DOM in priority?
I thought of
.card {
  &.is-dark {
    &, :not(.is-light) {
    }
  }
}

but it wouldn't work since it would be the is-dark that would apply while I'd expect the .is-light (in the case of .is-light within .is-dark).

As far as there is no direct content in your card, you can set color in the card and not in the p

Use CSS variables and inheritance will do the right job for you.


.card {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  &.is-dark {
    background: #151515;
    --color: white;
  }
  &.is-light {
    background: #fcfcfd;
    --color: #111;
  }
  p {
    color: var(--color);
  }
}
<div class="card is-light">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-dark">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card is-dark">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-light">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>



Actually you don't really need variables


.card {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  &.is-dark {
    background: #151515;
    color: white;
  }
  &.is-light {
    background: #fcfcfd;
    color: #111;
  }
}
<div class="card is-light">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-dark">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card is-dark">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-light">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>




If p is picking up a different color from elsewhere in the code, you can also add .card p { color: inherit; } to ensure that it takes its color from whatever is defined for the .card parent

In the example of color property, it can be assigned to a parent, but what if it is another one (eg. margin, :before etc.). The correct answer is definitely the CSS variable one. You should emphasis it more.

You can fix that by using > p, but CSS custom properties can become really handy for such situations and result in a - imho - cleaner solution.
For .card.is-dark and .card.is-light, you can specify what values  the properties should have, and you can then just use those on the elements you want to use.


.card.is-dark {
  --background-color: #151515;
  --text-color: white;
}

.card.is-light {
  --background-color: #fcfcfd;
  --text-color: 111;
}

.card {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background: var(--background-color);
  
  p {
    color: var(--text-color);
  }
}
<div class="card is-light">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-dark">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card is-dark">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-light">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>




I like that approach more than mine =)

If you limit your css so that it just targets the direct children then your approach works.
Obviously this has to be adapted, depending on how your actual card HTML will look like, I assume this is a dumbed down version of it. Maybe you can work with an additional wrapper to specify the content of a card for CSS selectors.


.card {
  padding: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid black;
  &.is-dark {
    background: #151515;
    > p {
      color: white;
    }
  }
  &.is-light {
    background: #fcfcfd;
    > p {
      color: #111;
    }
  }
}
<div class="card is-light">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-dark">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="card is-dark">
  <p>Some content</p>
  <div class="card is-light">
    <p>Some sub-content</p>
  </div>
</div>




Your solution works but unfortunately I can't guaranty that the <p> is a direct child of the .card in my case.
